# Use of @RolesAllowed in Quarkus with custom JWT validation, without smallrye-jwt

Tags: jakarta-ee, quarkus, microprofile

I need to use @RolesAllowed without smallrye-jwt because the project uses a JWT signed inside a JWE. We have an endpoin for that which will be called from a filter.

But if I remove the smallrye-jwt dependency, the @RolesAllowed annotation is no longer validated.

How could @RolesAllowed be used in Quarkus without smallrye-jwt?

Comment: why should you remove the jwt related dependency?

Comment: Because smallrye-jwt **only** validates a JWT signed with RSA, I need to read a JWE and validate the signed JWT (signed with SHA-512) found inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following guide to use @RolesAllowed: https://howtodoinjava.com/resteasy/resteasy-containerrequestfilter-example/